# Script Relationships only SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Is there a way in SQL server to generate a script to re-create all the foreign key constraints and relationships? Basically I need to delete all relationships and then need to re-script them against the database.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The question is either for MS SQL Server or MySQL. Wich of the tags is incorrect? Or you want the same for both RDBMS's?

Comment: Correct Both if Possible

Comment: Sorry new member, just realised how to accept and therefore I have updated my score

Comment: Great, there is always time to correct ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For MS SQL Server [here you have a full script](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2958.script-to-create-all-foreign-keys.aspx) with details and comments. And also you can use the SMSS to generate a create script of a table with all its necesary details. But this will do the work for only one table, if you need to do it for all tables and there are a lot, it could be a pain right there.

For MySQL, <strike>in case you needed it</strike> [check this link](http://www.justskins.com/forums/script-to-dynmically-create-127961.html)

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: @LenielMaccaferri corrected the link, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server Management Studio, you can select see your tables. You can walk through 1 by 1. Press right click on the table -> `Script Table As` -> `DROP And CREATE TO`.

With this the Studio will generate the drop constraints and alter table add constraints in a new query window.

Comment: I am looking for a script to mass script the relationships. There are hundreds of tables in the database, if this is the only solution then I will do it this way. Thanks for your answer